# Lie derivative of two differnt size related tensors

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, lie-derivative

Let $\bar{M}=I\times M$ be a pseudo-Riemannian manifold equipped with metric $\bar g=-dt^2\oplus f^2g$ where $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold, $I$ is an open connected interval and $f$ is a positive function on $I$.
The curvature tensor $\bar R$ on $\bar M$ is given by
$$\bar R(X,\partial_t,\partial_t,Y)=\frac{-\ddot f}{f}\bar g(X,Y)$$
where $X,Y\in {\frak X }( M)$. Now, I want to get the Lie derivative of $\bar R$ in direction of $h\partial_t$ where $h$ is a smooth function on $I$. Can I use
$$(\bar {\frak{L}}_{h\partial _t}\bar R)(X,\partial_t,\partial_t,Y)= (\bar {\frak{L}}_{h\partial _t}\bar g)(\frac{-\ddot f}{f}X,Y)$$ If not, why?
I computed both sides, they are not equal. My calculations may be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think that this would be correct? You are differentiating completely different objects on the left and right hand side. $g$ is not the same as $R$ (I'm omitting the bars).

Check [this site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative#Lie_derivative_of_tensor_fields) (scroll down to 'Lie derivative' of tensor fields) to check how to calculate
$${\frak{L}}_V (R(X, Z, Z, Y)) $$

(which results in 
$$({\frak{L}}_V R)(X, Z, Z, Y) + R({\frak{L}}_V X, Z, Z, Y)+\dots+R( X, Z, Z,{\frak{L}}_V Y) $$
where the first term of the resulting expression is what you are looking at tht left hand side in your eqaution. So to make use of your identity you have to solve for $({\frak{L}}_V R)(X, Z, Z, Y) $ first.)

Comment: I am OK with this formula and got the LHS using it. I want to understand why the RHS is different. You have repeated my question. We take the Lie derivative of both sides. Why they are different?

Comment: @SamehShenawy No, you don't take the Lie derivative of both sides. You are taking the derivative of   _parts_ of both sides, and these parts do _not_ represent the same object.

Comment: Now, I understand your point. I am going to check it

Comment: So you mean I should start with $$\bar {\frak{L}}_{h\partial _t}(\bar R(X,\partial_t,\partial_t,Y))= \bar {\frak{L}}_{h\partial _t}(\bar g(\frac{-\ddot f}{f}X,Y))$$

Comment: @SamehShenawy yes. This is the derivative of the same object on both sides, assuming your initial equation is correct.